# How can i solve this error ailed to save logic app?

Tags: sentinel, blackberry-playbook

I hope you do.
I have been creating a new playbook to submit a URL scan using the Virustotal website but I am getting blocked by this error; So can anyone help please, I need to fixe this error for my project ...

[first connexion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIZV0.png)  
[Second connexion, k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwNSF.png)